# Postman form-data image request setting image as undefined

Tags: node.js, express, postman, http-post, form-data

I'm trying to send an image file along with a plain text through postman request. I am using express on the backend. Here's a screenshot of the request:

[Image showing my postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TKfh.jpg)

I have two issues:

- In the endpoint, when I console req.body it logs an empty object. Therefore the request body is empty
- The image value when I check the console displays "undefined" despite the fact that I selected an image.

Here's an image displaying the postman console

[Image showing postman console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMQvj.jpg)

Comment: you should use multer module for management files in backend, https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi Yeah. I'm using multer, and I can get the body now. So the first issue is solved. But postman fails to send my image. So when I console "multer.files" it returns undefined

Comment: thats just in the console but the file get sends correctly. the issue shown is that your endpoint not able to recognize "name" make shure thats the correct key

Comment: @PDHide Thanks guys, I've solved it. Yes it kept displaying undefined while still sending the image...